# How does Tomohiko Sakamoto's Algorithm work? need details explanation

Tags: c, algorithm, math, dayofweek

Following function represents Sakamoto's Algorithm from Wikipedia page-
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

```
int dow(int y, int m, int d) {
    /* 1 <= m <= 12,  y > 1752 (in the U.K.) */
    static int t[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};
    y -= m < 3;  
    return (y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;
}
```

i do not understand how does the algorithm work? especially, the t[] array.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is quite straightforward:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

```
if (year is not divisible by 4) then (it is a common year)
else
if (year is not divisible by 100) then (it is a leap year)
else
if (year is not divisible by 400) then (it is a common year)
else (it is a leap year)
```

t[] is a table with "#/days" offset for each month.

Answer (score 2):

The result of a comparison is an `int` containing 0 or 1. So this line

```
y -= m < 3;
```

means "if the month is January or February, the leap day *for this year* has not yet occurred".